# Error: Virtual path "password" conflicts with a real path in the schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I am  trying to add Virtuals in my schema I am getting following error and could not able to solve it... Please help to resolve it and please let me know why this is happeing

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var recipientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, trim: true, required:  true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});


/**
 * Virtuals
 */
recipientSchema
  .virtual('password')
  .set(function(password) {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = this.makeSalt();
    this.hashedPassword = this.encryptPassword(password);
  })
  .get(function() {
    return this._password;
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipients', recipientSchema);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use virtual **'password'** you don't need to declare the real one in schema. Also you haven't declared **hashedPassword** and **salt**

Your Schema must be like this

```
var recipientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, trim: true, required:  true },
  hashedPassword: { type: String, required: true },
  salt: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this schema :

[image]

Here, we have created password field virtual, i.e. when we post data, we'll use with the password field, but it will store as hash_password in the database (password field won't appear in database as we made it virtual), and we don't need to create fields for password  separately in the schema.

Look at the form(post data) for post data :

[image]

And fields in database will store like this :

[image]

Hope this will clear your doubts.